# Firefox: Downloading files with drag and drop

Tags: firefox, download, drag-and-drop

In Firefox, if you drag and drop a URL (pointing to MyDocument.PDF, for example) into [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm) (or Windows Explorer), Firefox will create a link (MyDocument.URL pointing to MyDocument.PDF) instead of downloading the PDF file.

Is it possible to actually download the file instead of getting a .url file?

To be more clear: I want to get the actual file when I drag and drop it, instead of getting a URL.

---

*Yes, I know, I could use 'Save target as...' in the contextual menu but this will open an additional 'where to save' dialog box. I want to do it in one step.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG!  I just find out that this feature is already implemented but not in Firefox, in Total Commander! More exactly it does exactly what I want if do a 'shift + drag and drop'. This will open a 'Connect to web host' box that will download the file.

Anyway, anyone can post a solution that will work from within Firefox, I will accept that solution instead of mine (because mine will work of course only with Total Commander).

Answer (score 1):

Try [DragIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dragit-formerly-drag-de-go). This extension allows you to drag and drop files to save on your disk.

Comment: I looks like it won't save the file to Windows Explorer current's folder but to predefined list of folder. +1 anyway. The plug in is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold down `Ctrl` while dragging and dropping. Seems to work with Firefox 40 and Nautilus 3.16.2 on Linux. I tried Googling but found no references to this anywhere.